# NSInvalidArgument error - CGImageRef from CIImage

Tags: ios, core-image, nserror, cgimageref

I'm getting an error on some code that two days ago was running fine.  The error is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType extent]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1bc8f0'
```

it points to this line on main.m:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Using logs to see where my code gets to it seems this line is throwing the error:

```
greySave = [context createCGImage:greyscaleImage fromRect:[greyscaleImage extent]];
```

greySave is a CGImageRef, declared at the start of my view controller.  It's simple grabbing a CIImage output and converting it to a CGImageRef for saving:

```
desaturate = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, colourSave, @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.00], nil];


greyscaleImage = [desaturate valueForKey:@"outputImage"];


greySave = [context createCGImage:greyscaleImage fromRect:[greyscaleImage extent]];
```

The only thing I have changed that I think (although do not understand why) could be causing the problem is adding an extra conditional statement, which would apply a second filter is the user wishes to do so:

```
if ([_alphaButtonSavedState isEqualToString:@"ON"]) {
             NSLog(@"user does want alpha on greyscale");
            //user wants alpha mask also  
        } else {
             NSLog(@"user does not want alpha on greyscale");
            //convert to CGImage for saving
            greySave = [context createCGImage:greyscaleImage fromRect:[greyscaleImage extent]];
             NSLog(@"greySave cgimage created");

            //save the grey image
            [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:greySave metadata:[greyscaleImage properties] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"ERROR in greyscale save: %@", error);
                } else
                {
                    NSLog(@"SUCCESS in greyscale save");
                    //in here we'll put a nice animation or something
                    //CGImageRelease(greyscaleImage);
                }
            }];
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is the entire chunk of code, just in case that helps.

```
[stillImage captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

    NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];  //get the raw image data from the session
    UIImage *startImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];  //create a UIImage from that image data, let's us work with it

    //resizing of image to take place before anything else
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithImage:startImage scaledToSize:_exportSSize];  //scale the image so it's shortest side is the size given in prefs

    NSLog(@"image width post scale: %g", image.size.width);
    NSLog(@"image height post scale is: %g", image.size.height);

    //change the context to render using cpu, so on app exit renders get completed
    context = [CIContext contextWithOptions: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer]];

    //new crop testing - not using CIImage - seems to work, just need to sort out crop region
    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, _exportSize, _exportSize);
    UIImage *cropper = [self imageByCropping:image toRect:cropRect];

    //the colour image is always saved so create a CGImage to save later
    colourSave = [cropper CGImage];
    NSLog(@"coloursave image created");

    //now we convert and create CGImages based upon chosen export options
    if ([_greyButtonSavedState isEqualToString:@"ON"]) {
        NSLog(@"inside the greyscale conditional");
        //user wants greyscale image
        //create a CIMonochrome filter 
        desaturate = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, colourSave, @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.00], nil];
         NSLog(@"desat ci filter created");
        //get the output
        greyscaleImage = [desaturate valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
         NSLog(@"dest output image created");

        //if the user wants to add the alpha
        if ([_alphaButtonSavedState isEqualToString:@"ON"]) {
             NSLog(@"user does want alpha on greyscale");
            //user wants alpha mask also  
        } else {
             NSLog(@"user does not want alpha on greyscale");
            //convert to CGImage for saving
            greySave = [context createCGImage:greyscaleImage fromRect:[greyscaleImage extent]];
             NSLog(@"greySave cgimage created");

            //save the grey image
            [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:greySave metadata:[greyscaleImage properties] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"ERROR in greyscale save: %@", error);
                } else
                {
                    NSLog(@"SUCCESS in greyscale save");
                    //in here we'll put a nice animation or something
                }
            }];
        }
    }
```

--  two more conditionals here, both currently empty

-- followed by a save for the colourSave image, this works fine.

-- then the method ends.

One more thing, this is how I'm cropping the image.  The returned image from the following method is what I create a CIImage from:

```
-(UIImage *)imageByCropping:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
```

{
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);

```
UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);

return cropped;
```

}

Comment: If it helps, the input image to the CIFilter is a UIImage.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the line where you create the `CGImage` and see what `greyscaleImage` is set to? The error is saying that the object `greyscaleImage` doesn't implement an `-extent` method. Could `greyscaleImage` either be nil or some other type of object?

Comment: @user1118321 logically, greyscaleImage is a CGImage because it inherits from NSCFType.  It isn't nil, because then it wouldn't crash, as messages to nil produce nil.

Comment: I'm creating greyscaleImage as a CIImage:  CIImage *greyscaleImage;  As I say, this error did not occur before, using the same method to convert and save.  The colour image saves.  I'll post the entire code chunk as that may help.

Comment: The conditional makes no difference, so I wonder if it has anything to do with the method I use to crop the image, shown here:  -(UIImage *)imageByCropping:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([imageToCrop CGImage], rect);
    
    UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    
    return cropped;
}

Comment: If I try to log the extent It throws the same error: greyscaleImage = [desaturate outputImage];  //get the output
             NSLog(@"dest output image created");
            
            NSLog(@"greyscaleImage width is: %f", greyscaleImage.extent.size.width);
            NSLog(@"greyscaleImage height is: %f", greyscaleImage.extent.size.height);

Comment: @user1118321 pointed me in the right direction, there was no extent because I was feeding a CGImage into a CIFilter, instead of a CIImage.  No errors were thrown so I didn't spot it straight away.

I'm now feeding a CIImage into the filter and converting the export, and all is good.  I can now finish my app :)  Just need to test test test and tweak tweak tweak. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding the answer in case it helps anyone else.

I was passing a UIImage into the CIFilter, this was causing the problem.  Converting the UIImage into a CIImage and passing that in resolved the issue.